# For ASP.NET Programmers: Does the executable 'dcpromo' have any significance?

Tags: cloud-computing, saml, adfsv2, sso, asp.net

`Dcpromo.exe` is famous among MCSEs for being they only way to create a Windows Domain Controller (in other words an Active Directory Domain) ... which in turn is often used by the ASP.NET Membership system.

I'm trying to determine if I should put content on "www.dcpromo.com" geared for developers or more towards sysadmins.

To me, a logical extension of this "domain controller on the internet" is to use WIF for the ASP.NET Membership system.  We'd then have a website that will serve the developer's interests in the SSO, SAML, user managment and identity areas we all struggle with.

So my question is:

**Q:**  Do programmers see a connection between the utility `dcpromo.exe` and ASP.NET Membership?  If so does it make sense to have a purpose of http://www.dcpromo.com  help developers in the areas of membership and cloud computing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been a Microsoft developer for 11 years, mostly as a web developer.  Been coding since 1.1 and I've used .NET membership in many of my applications, and I've never heard of dcpromo.

Comment: +1 - About 9 years of ASP.NET here and never heard of dcpromo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an asp.net newbie, having been working with it for only about 3 months, though I've played with membership a little bit.  That said, I've never heard of dcpromo.  Just my 2 cents.